# How to use fields in query evaluated criteria expressions in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In Mongodb, I have a tasks collection, which has following fields, along with 25 other fields

```
1. timeToLive - holds the number of minutes
2. createdDate - holds the ISODate
```

I need to write a query, which will return me only unexpired tasks. I am trying something like following:

```
db.tasks.find({"timeToLive":{$gt:((new Date().getTime()-createdDate)/60000)}},{_id:1, createdDate:1, timeToLive:1})
```

The problem is that mongo does not recognize createdDate in $gt expression as a field from the document. I get following error:

```
2015-05-16T16:47:03.573-0400 E QUERY ReferenceError: createdDate is not defined at (shell):2:48
```

How do i write the field name there so that it is treated as field not a variable? I tried putting the field name in double quotes but then it is treated as a string literal.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mongo is not going to let you do that. You can't use a property of a document within a query.  you'd have to do this logic if your app or maybe create a property called 'expiresAt' that you could use to tell when the document expires.

Comment: Thanks @ThrowsException for commenting. I do paging within mongo queries and if i filter jobs in the app, that messes up with number of document returned from collection and the number i am left with after i am done filtering expired tasks. If i am not able to find how to do this in query, then i will use an alternate way like creating a new property or enhancing app logic to filter and maintain paging integrity.

Comment: I think you're best bet is to try an expiresAt. You're queries will be a lot easier to write and you'll have a single field you can index. Your other option is you can leverage Mongo's TTL index that will delete anything in the database that expires automatically. But that's a choice you have to make if it's important to keep data around that has expired for archiving purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in a regular MongoDB find query. But fortunately it is possible to achieve your desired result using Mongo's aggregation framework in the following way:

```js
db.tasks.aggregate([
    {$project: 
        {
           timeToLive: 1, 
           createdDate: 1, 
           expired:
           {
               $gt: [
                   {
                      $divide: [
                          {
                             $subtract: [new Date(), "$createdDate"]
                          }, 
                          60000
                       ]
                   },
                   "$timeToLive"
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {$match:
        {
            expired: false
        }
    }, 
    {$project: 
        {
           timeToLive: 1, 
           createdDate: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This works. Can you please explain why the following does not work?db.jobs.find({ "timeToLive": { $gt: { $divide: [ { $subtract: [new Date(), "$createdDate"] }, 60000 ] } } },{_id:1, createdDate:1, timeToLive:1})

Comment: Because that operators are aggregation operators, they do not work for regular queries

Comment: Moreover, if you have noticed, the syntax of `$gt` operator is different for regular and aggregation queries.